# Symfony 3.2.1 FOSUserBundle templates as child

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm new in symfony and i'm trying to overwrite FOSUserBundle templates as child. Copying to src/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views works, but want to do this with child bundle.

I create ser/UserBundle/UserBundle.php

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
        public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }

}
```

Then, i've made Entity:

```
<?php
// src/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

configure parameters.yml, security.yml and routing.yml.

logically works, i can /login /register etc. 
Now i want to overwrite layout.html.twig so i creating src/UserBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Demo Application{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
    Ala ma kota
{% endblock %}
```

But this is not rendered :/
profiler says:

```
Rendering Call Graph

main 4.04ms/100%
└ @FOSUser/Security/login.html.twig 1.78ms/44%
│ └ @FOSUser/layout.html.twig 1.69ms/42%
│   └ @FOSUser/Security/login.html.twig::block(fos_user_content)
│     └ @FOSUser/Security/login_content.html.twig
└ @WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar_js.html.twig 2.26ms/56%
  └ @WebProfiler/Profiler/base_js.html.twig
```

I do this according to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvLUvOaW_XY&t=512s, but this video is about symfony 2.0 and I try with Symfony 3.2. Does something changed in Symfony3 with childrening bundles?
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added your child bundle in `AppKernel` class?

Comment: Yes, this was added first

Comment: I installed Symfony 2.8 with FOS 2.0 and the same effect, layout wasn't rendered from my bundle. But later I installed Symfony 2.8 and FOS 1.3 and I was surprissed, it was working adn was rendered from my bundle. But why in v2.0 isn't?

Comment: I've found reason of this behavior :/ https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2376

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got same problem after last update :(